# HtmlDocument get form

Tags: asp.net, dom

I'm working with HtmlDocument and HtmlWeb. I usually get the form element by its id using:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

//get the form
doc.LoadHtml(htmlPreviousForm);
var form = doc.GetElementbyId("postingForm");
```

However, the page that I'm working the form that I want doesn't have name, id, or class:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="go" value="[x]" title="delete">x</button>
</form>
```

How can I get the action of this form using HtmlDocument?

Comment: Do you have many forms there?

Comment: No, just one form

Comment: why don't you add a name to your form?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852165/extracting-inner-text-from-html-body-node-with-html-agility-pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the form by id you can use `SelectSingleNode`

```
var form = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form");
```