# Fetch Title, Description and Image from facebook URL

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

I have a messaging app in which I need one API that returns the title, image, and description of a particular Facebook URL (Facebook (Public) POST). I have AppId as well as App Secret. I am using c# (.net core).
I just can't find out the way to fetch the title, image, and description of a particular Facebook link. I would love to get all your suggestions.

**Note**: Although I'm able to get all other URL data (Twitter, Youtube, General Articles).

Comment: possible duplicate of : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158091/how-to-extract-a-urls-title-images-and-description-using-html-agility-utility

Comment: @yashSoni, thank you for your response, but I tried that method. sometimes it works... sometimes It doesn't. So now I am trying by passing appid and appsecret

Comment: You do not get automatic API access to all data, just because it might be "public" in the frontend pages. If you do not have admin access to the page, then your app would need to get the [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access) feature approved first; but the only allowed usage is to _"Provide competitive benchmark analysis."_