# HtmlAgilityPack remove childnode of childnode

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a string containing something like this :

```
string text = "<p>test <span> <font> here </font> </span> try</p><p> <font> try 2</font> </p>"
```

What I need is to filter something like this :

Keep Text inside P
Remove Span and content (font and text)
Keep Text inside font if its direct parent is not a Span*

What I have is :

```
StringBuilder sbtexttoCorrect = new StringBuilder();
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(textToFormat);
var nodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");

foreach (var line in nodes)
{
   if (line.Name =="SPAN")
   {
      line.RemoveAllChildren();
      line.Remove();
   }
}
foreach (var txt in nodes)
{
sbtexttoCorrect.Append(txt.InnerText);
}
```

But the sbtexttoCorrect at then end still gets the child font of the span. Even with the Removechild and his own Remove.

What am I missing?

**Note** : on another post someone told me :

```
 foreach (var line in nodes.Select(node => node.ChildNodes.Where(
     childNode => childNode.Name != "span"))
                    .Select(
                        textNodes => textNodes.Aggregate(String.Empty, (current, node) => current + node.InnerText)))
        {

            sbtexttoCorrect.Append(line);
        }
```

But I do not understand all of the syntax so I wanted to rewrite my own try, plus it did not work all the time too, it is still getting the text inside the Font inside the Span.

**Note 2** I can't find any doc on the specification of the Agilty Pack. If someone knows where to find it, I'd like to learn more about this library.

**Edit** The real HTML is way more complexe, with a number of childNode that I can't know for sur, they can be TD or DIV, the only thing really sure is when there is a span I need to skip his content and his childNode

Comment: I edited my answer. It now removes all spans independently at which level they are in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see these problems in your code:

- You treat the span as UpperCase whereas HtmlAgilityPack handles it as LowerCase => your if block will never hit
- You only loop on the p elements (instead on the childs of p elements) => your if block will never hit

Based on your additional explications this should work:

- It selects all spans with an XPath (so should work for upper and lower case)
- It removes the spans
- It cleans all html elements (as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182594/grab-all-text-from-html-with-html-agility-pack))

  ```
  string text = "<p>test <SPAN> <font> here </font> </SPAN> try</p><p><table> <tr><td><span>test</span></td></tr></table><font> try 2</font> </p>";
  StringBuilder sbtexttoCorrect = new StringBuilder();
  HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
  html.LoadHtml(text);
  var nodes = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span");

  foreach (var node in nodes)
  {
      node.Remove();
  }

  foreach (var node in html.DocumentNode.DescendantsAndSelf())
  {
      if (!node.HasChildNodes)
      {
          string t = node.InnerText;
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
              sbtexttoCorrect.AppendLine(t);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: well the string I use might have the node written in UpperCase but i tryed it with LowerCase too. In your case, the text inside the <font> inside the <span> won't be taken because you don't leap througt the <span> childnode ?

Comment: Yes and isn't that what you want? "Keep Text inside P Remove Span and content (font and text) Keep Text inside font if its direct parent is not a Span*"

Comment: yes this is what I wanted, but that means that in the case I got a table, he wont got through all the table and watch all the child, he will only iterate over the two first level of childnode ?

Comment: After trying it, it still get the Text inside the Font of the Span where he sould not be

Comment: The code I posted gives "test  try  try 2" . You say you don't get the same output ?

Comment: Yes, I get : tes here test try try 2; I sometimes get two times the value behing Append to my stringBuilder. and it's like the first loop take all, even the font inside the span then a second loop occur where it take only what we said

Comment: It must be something in your code or the way you integrated the code. Can you copy and paste only the code from my answer to a command line project and execute it ?

Comment: Well it is the only thing I do, i only do HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(sbtexttoCorrect.ToString()); before returning what I have in my string builder. This is why i don't get it

Comment: This issue might come from the construction of the HTMLBecause it's acutally way more complexe then my exemple, so i think I need more iteration then only 2, that might be Why He still get the span and his font some times

Comment: Sorry. I removed my remark. Seems to work just fine.

Comment: Dude that is totally this, Thanks a lot, I might modify it a little now that i will be able to understand how to go through all element so he match some specifique case.