# HTML to Text Email Converter in C#

Tags: c#, email, html-email

I'm looking for code or a library in C# that convert HTML email format to plain text format. I want to send my emails with both format. 
Also, I would like the href links to be converted to text as well. Exactly how mailchimp does it here: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/html-to-text/
Any idea?

Comment: You can strip tags from the string, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286813/how-do-you-convert-html-to-plain-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HtmlAgilityPack and loop through nodes to extract text. Example: [Grab all text from html with Html Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182594/grab-all-text-from-html-with-html-agility-pack)