# Remove Html white space (&nbsp;) using c#

Tags: c#, html, string, text

I use this method to convert html text to plain text. But it can't remove `&nbsp;` or white space. Can you help me to change and solve it?

Method :

```
public string HtmlToPlainText(string htmlText)
    {
        htmlText = htmlText.Replace("&nbsp;",string.Empty);
        //const string tagWhiteSpace = @"(>|$)(\W|\n|\r)+<";//matches one or more (white space or line breaks) between '>' and '<'
        const string stripFormatting = @"<[^>]*>";//match any character between '<' and '>', even when end tag is missing
        const string lineBreak = @"<(br|BR)\s{0,1}\/{0,1}>";//matches: <br>,<br/>,<br />,<BR>,<BR/>,<BR />
        var lineBreakRegex = new Regex(lineBreak, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var stripFormattingRegex = new Regex(stripFormatting, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        //var tagWhiteSpaceRegex = new Regex(tagWhiteSpace, RegexOptions.Multiline);

        var text = htmlText;
        //Decode html specific characters
        text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
        //Remove tag whitespace / line breaks
        //text = tagWhiteSpaceRegex.Replace(text, "><");
        //Replace < br /> with line breaks
        text = lineBreakRegex.Replace(text, Environment.NewLine);
        //Strip formatting
        text = stripFormattingRegex.Replace(text, string.Empty);
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered avoiding Tony the Pony by loading the document into eg HtmlAgilityPack and pulling the //text of every node? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182594/grab-all-text-from-html-with-html-agility-pack

Comment: @gunr [He comes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1410664)

Comment: A Unicode non-breaking space is U+00A0. Have you tried using `"\u00A0"` explicitly.  And, as pointed out by other comments, you will only get frustrated by trying to do this with Regex